# How to inherit partner ledger report template from account module in odoo?

Tags: report, odoo-8, openerp-8

How can i inherit partner ledger report template which is available in account module so when i go to accounting > customer > selecting some customer like agrolait > click on print button > click on partner ledger > now click again on print its showing me some extra content like chart of account, fiscalyear, fiterby etc. which i don't require.

Means i need to re-design the template according to me by replacing unwanted contents. 
Can anyone help me to resolve this problem.
Any answer would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an Openerp 6/8 user, but hopefully you'll be able to translate my answer to Odoo.

Firstly, the docs - https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html#inheritance

Normally, you need to do three things - find a place WHERE you want to do your inheritance, inherit Python model and then, finally, inherit the views.

If you ONLY need to change the view without accessing data other than already available, then usually you can skip the Python inheritance part. As I understand, this is the case.

From the docs:

```
<!-- improved idea categories list -->
    <record id="idea_category_list2" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">id.category.list2</field>
        <field name="model">idea.category</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="id_category_list"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <!-- find field description and add the field
                 idea_ids after it -->
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='description']" position="after">
              <field name="idea_ids" string="Number of ideas"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

You need to add data to xml-file (either already existing or by creating a new file) in a module which has the inherited module in its dependencies. What is this data, you ask? Well, it's a view inheritance record! Based on the example above, let me explain all of the fields:

> - record_id is the new, unique name for your view inheritance (uses underscore, as dots imply you're overwriting a view from another
>     module, which you don't need to do as long as you're not completely
>     replacing the view). In record_id, model is always 'ir.ui.view', since you're
>     working with a view.
> - model is the same as in the inherited view.
> - name is the new, unique name for your view inheritance (uses mainly dots as spaces)
> - inherit_id - and this is **the important part**. Using notation module_name.view_id, here you're providing the view_id you're
>     inheriting.

As for the content in the 'arch' tags, this is where you use xpath to find the area you want to edit or replace. In the case of the example above, this inherit finds the field 'description' and inserts 'idea_ids' field after it.

If you need more help, either check the documentation I've linked to or come back here and ask away!

---

As for report inheritance, just to repent myself.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html#report-template

I think that what you need to do is to overwrite the report record, like the one below, by creating a new `<report>` record in a xml life. The difference between the inherited report record and your new record would be, usually, only in "id" and "file" values.

```
   <report
        id="account_invoices"
        model="account.invoice"
        string="Invoices"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="account.report_invoice"
        file="account.report_invoice"
        attachment_use="True"
        attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and
            ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
    />
```

In the case of Odoo 6 (and hopefully 8), you overwrite a report record by changing its id to /module_name.inherited_id/. For example, if you're inheriting the account_invoice_summary report from "account" module, the id would be "account.account_invoice_summary". The second thing would be to change the "file" value to the one corresponding to edited template. It depends on a few factors - are you trying to create a printed report (which I assume you're trying to do), or something else?

Comment: Hi Bish can u please explain me  if i need to inherit report template of partner ledger for that is it compulsry to inherit the py file and xml. file of account.partner.ledger

Comment: I apologize - for some reason I thought you're talking about a view, and then I've posted an useless answer.

Comment: In case of openerp 6, all I need to do is to overwrite the <report> record of the template and provide new report file. If it's the same here, I don't think Python inheritance is actually necessary.

Comment: okay so do you have any idea about report  template inheritance

Comment: can u provide some syntaxes

Comment: i was asking about template inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got the solution of this question please have look this 
go to `Setting > Reports > Reports > filter partner` in search and then open `partner > go to search associated qweb view > open report_partnerledger > select EXTERNAL ID`; this is your inherit_id.
Most important don't forget to upgrade base module because it depends on res.partner so if you upgrade only your module then it will show an error of external id not found so after base module upgradation now you can change or replace anything like I have changed in below:

```
<template id="report_partnerledger_inherit2" inherit_id="account.report_partnerledger">

        <xpath expr="//h2" position="replace">
            <h1>Ipshita Nandan</h1>
         </xpath>

         <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-3']" position="replace">
            <strong>Change chart of account:</strong>
         </xpath>

         <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-3']" position="replace">
            <strong>change fiscal year:</strong>
         </xpath>

         <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-3']" position="replace">
            <strong>Change Journals:</strong>
         </xpath>

         <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-3']" position="replace">
            <strong>Change partner's:</strong>
         </xpath>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the inherit ID of partner ledger report from the settings, under reports, and use it in your template as shown below and upgrade base module.

```
<template id="report_partnerledger_inherit2" inherit_id="account.report_partnerledger">

        <xpath expr="//h2" position="replace">
            <h1>replace and add anythings  </h1>
         </xpath>

         <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-3']" position="replace">
            <strong>Change chart of account:</strong>
         </xpath>

         <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-3']" position="replace">
            <strong>change fiscal year:</strong>
         </xpath>

</template>
```